# 3d array An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 3 dimensional array with some values from database, but I'm getting an error that doesn't tell me too much. Any idea what it can be?

`db_pstackNr` is a string formed by numbers (2,3)

`db_stackValue` is a string formed by 48 elements (A,B,C,D,empty)

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /license/console.jsp at line 51 (multi[i][j][n] = stackValue[k];)

```java
int stackNr = 2;    
String [] ar_pstackNr = db_pstackNr.split(",");
String [] stackValue = db_stackValue.split(",");

String [][][] multi = new String [stackNr][][];
int [] pstackNr = new int[ar_pstackNr.length];
int palet = 16, m=0, n=0;

for(int i = 0; i < stackNr; i++) {
    pstackNr[i] = Integer.parseInt(ar_pstackNr[i]);

    for(int j = 0; j < pstackNr[i]; j++) {

        if (i > 0) {
            palet += 16; m +=16;
        }
        for(int k = m; k < palet; k++) {
            multi[i][j][n] = stackValue[k];
            n++;
            out.println(multi[i][j][n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The root cause might be burried in the exception stack chain. find it. I am guessing IndexArrayOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I'm debugging the code and I see that **multi** is getting value **null**, but nu idea why

Comment: what is that line 51 of the JSP when the error occured?

Comment: Should not you be using `k` instead of `n` for `multi` in the expression `multi[i][j][n] = stackValue[k];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have 2nd dimension of **multi** initialized, but you are trying to access it with **j** index.